# Function executes regardless of the localStorage if statement

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, local-storage

I'm trying to execute a JavaScript function depending on the value of a localStorage key. It seems pretty easy, but I'm not getting anywhere. Here's what I have currently -

```
        <script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        setInterval(function()
        {
            var one = localStorage.getItem('one');
            if (one !== true)
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                elem.className = "hide";
            } 
            else if (one !== false) 
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                elem.className = "show";
            }
            else {
                var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                elem.className = "show";
            }
        }, 50);
    }
</script>
```

What this is supposed to do is check every 50ms for the key "one" in localStorage. If it's true, execute the function defined under the if statement. If it's false, execute the other function that's defined under the else or else if statements.

Unfortunately, it doesn't matter whether or not there is even an entry in localStorage at all, it always executes the first function(hiding the object). I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit - I couldn't find this information in other posts, mainly because my issue has to do with the points brought up in the comments and answers. If the string `"true"` isn't in localStorage to begin with, why is the function still executing?

Comment: `localStorage` returns a string, not a boolean.

Comment: Hm. So how would I go about avoiding/making this functional?(Sorry, I'm still learning a lot of this stuff)

Comment: Either compare to string constants (`==="false"`, `==="true"`) or parse it (simplest with `JSON.parse`)

Comment: Ah. Thanks! Sorry for the dupe by the way, I couldn't find my specific answer using the search bar.

Comment: @Bergi Do you want to submit that as an answer? If others see this question I'd like a big green checkmark next to your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything stored in localStore is strictly to store *string* key/value pairs. This means you are actually storing the string: `"true"` and not the boolean value `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not really understanding though. If the string `"true"` isn't there to begin with, why is it still executing?

Comment: Because ("true" !== true) resolves to true. It will always execute since no matter what is returned will not be a boolean true value.